# RMSE calculation for random forest in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am reasonably new to R and have a question I hope you could help me with. I would like to calculate RMSE between tested and predicted dataset.

```
train = cdat[ii,]
test = cdat[-ii,]
rffit = randomForest(price~.,data=train,mtry=2,ntree=500)
rfvalpred = predict(rffit,newdata=test)
rmse = sqrt(mean((test$price-rfvalpred)^2))
```

Somehow I get a very wrong number for RMSE like 400, any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: Why is 400 a "very wrong number"? It looks like a random forest with regression trees (assuming price is continuous) in which case RMSE can be pretty much any non-negative number according to how well your model fits. If you consider 400 wrong, maybe the model is bad in this case. Without data it is hard to say anything else.

Comment: But should RMSE here not be a number below 1?

Comment: Of course not. The RMSE takes values between [0, Inf). The closer to zero the better the model. Look at your formula. What makes you think it would produce a number between 0 and 1?

Comment: Oh ok, sorry.  The model includes categorical variables. could that be the issue? Would you know how I could select for the randomforest only 2 variables? I saw to drop would be -variable name

Comment: I thought when loading the data R will recognize the categorical variables

Comment: Categorical variables are not an issue for any random forest algorithm, and there is no issue with the RMSE being high. You provide no data so it would be hard to say anything else. If you have another question please ask it as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your RMSE can take values between [0, +Inf) depending on your dataset. 400 might be the correct answer for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you might want to use **log1p** and **Metrics** lib:

```
require(Metrics) # install.packages('Metrics') if not installed
...
y_train = ...
y_predictions = ...

# Manual Calc ...
rmse <- sqrt(mean(as.matrix(log1p(y_train) - log1p(y_predictions))^2))
print(paste('RMSE:', rmse))
# ... Metrics lib
rmse <- rmse(log1p(as.matrix(y_train)), log1p(y_predictions))
print(paste('RMSE:', rmse))
```

Hope it helps.